# Connect robo 3T with PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, robo3t

I would like to know if it is possible to connect a **Robo 3T** collection with **Power BI**?

Do you have any suggestions to recover data automatically from Robo 3T in Power BI?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robo 3T is a mongoDB GUI. Underlying is the MongoDB object. To connect to MongoDB PowerBI doesn't have direct connector yet. But you can try ODBC connectivity.

1. Create a system [DSN](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/tutorial/create-system-dsn)
2. Use that system DSN to [connect](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/connect/powerbi) to the data source.